# cshtml file and database connection pool for MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, razor, database-connection, connection-pooling

I am doing a single CSHTML page for demo purpose. The page opens a connection to the backend MS SQL database in the following way:

```
var db = Database.Open("connection_string");
```

I am curious about the following scenario:

Suppose this page gets a lot of requests. I come from the Java world and I understand that a database connection pool can help in performance.

My question: how can I set up a database connection pool in this system setup (a single CSHTML file, IIS, MS SQL server)?

Thanks so much for any info.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADO.NET pools connections automatically. In .NET pooling is almost never an issue and by default on. It is rare to have to deal with it at all.

If you didn't turn it off, it is on and works without you noticing any difference. You can set it to off in the connection string. If yours doesn't say anything about pooling, all is well.

To a .NET dev it is strange that with Java pooling is something to think about. Connection overhead is a multiple of the cost of executing a cheap query. Without pooling performance is totally destroyed. You must have pooling in most cases.

Comment: usr, thanks sooo much for your information. I am glad to know that .NET handles it automatically in the backend. Could you update your post with "where to turn it on/off"? I wanted to make sure it is on in my case.

Comment: Could you please update your post with your above comment? I want this post to have a complete answer, which would be easier for other people like me. I will select your post as the answer. Again, thanks!

Comment: Why should he? This is well documented. If you have any questions regarding connection strings - head over to http://connectionstrings.com/ ;)